# ASP.NET MVC 4 Action on AJAX Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to call a javascript function every time an AJAX request is sent, and then another when the call is finished? I know you can do it individually for each form with the OnBegin and OnComplete functions, but I want a universal one.

Specifically, I would like the wait cursor to show every time it sends an ajax call, and then go back to the default cursor when done.

With webforms you could do

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequest);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);
```

but I need something for MVC 4.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this task would be appreciated, or alternatives if it's just a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tr this [global ajax event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)